# Extend apps under the macbook notch

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Is it possible to extend apps under (not below) the notch? In many cases, this wouldn't be a problem but would allow more screen real estate.

[image: app goes all the way up to the top bezel]

The effect in the image is achieved with the accessibility zoom.

Comment: I would really like to have a way to do this, did you find anything?

Comment: Not yet. But I’m considering creating an advanced status area there. BetterTouchTool allows putting webviews there, if you’re familiar with it. It essentially allows creating an Electron app by replicating the needed functionality to interact with the Mac in BTT.

Comment: Interesting idea. However, I would like to use that space to gain screen surface, and I don't really desire any menu/status bars. I hope someone will figure out how to do it

Comment: Same here. It’s just in case that nothing happens. I always hide my menu bar so it’s lost space for now. And it looks incredible with the thin borders all around, but the thick top border ruins that experience.

Comment: This is, honest to god, the most idiotic thing Apple has ever done.

Comment: I found this (hack): https://notes.alinpanaitiu.com/Fullscreen%20apps%20above%20the%20MacBook%20notch